# sscanf usage - how to verify a completed scan vs an aborted scan

Tags: c, formatting, scanf

My database provides a textfile with opening and closing `"` to delimiter formulas.
The set of formulas is very limited and will be easy to implement once identified.
I try to use scanf to get the parameters and i want to use the delimiter `"` to provide a mechanism for scanf to fail.

In the below example the last delimiter is ignored and the information that the delimiter was not found is lost. How can i control if sscanf was able to match the whole string?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

unsigned printIdentity(const char * formula){
    unsigned e = 0, found = 0;
    double a, b;
    printf("-------------\n");
    printf("INVESTIGATING: %s\n", formula);
    if( ( 2 == sscanf_s( formula, " \" X * %lf %lf \" ", &a, &b, sizeof( double ), sizeof( double ) ) ) ){
        printf("MATCH: X * %lf + %lf\n", a, b);
        ++found;
    }
    if( ( 1 == sscanf_s( formula, " \" X * %lf \" ", &a, sizeof( double ) ) ) ){
        printf("MATCH: X * %lf\n", a);
        ++found;
    }
    if( found != 1){
        e += 1;
        printf("ERROR: %u formula types\n", found);
    }
    printf("-------------\n");
    return e;
}

unsigned main( void )
{
    unsigned e = 0;

    e += printIdentity("     \"X*3.1\"");
    e += printIdentity("     \"X*3.2-4.2\"");
    e += printIdentity("     \"X*3.3+4.3\"");

    if( 0 != e ){ printf( "ERRORS: %2u\n", e ); }
    else{ printf( "all pass\n", e ); }
    return e;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How can i control if sscanf was able to match the whole string?

Use the format specifier `%n` to obtain the position where processing ended and compare with the length of the input string, where the `n` format specifier is defined as (from section *7.19.6.2 The fscanf function* of the C99 standard):

> No input is consumed. The corresponding argument shall be a pointer to
>   signed integer into which is to be written the number of characters read from
>   the input stream so far by this call to the fscanf function. Execution of a
>   %n directive does not increment the assignment count returned at the
>   completion of execution of the fscanf function. No argument is converted,
>   but one is consumed. If the conversion specification includes an assignmentsuppressing
>   character or a field width, the behavior is undefined.

For example:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    const char* good_input = "\"20 21\"";
    const char* bad_input = "\"14 12";
    int a[2];
    int pos;

    if (sscanf(good_input, " \"%d %d\"%n", &a[0], &a[1], &pos) == 2 &&
        pos == strlen(good_input))
    {
        printf("good_input: %d %d\n", a[0], a[1]);
    }

    if (sscanf(bad_input, " \"%d %d\"%n", &a[0], &a[1], &pos) == 2 &&
        pos == strlen(bad_input))
    {
        printf("bad_input: %d %d\n", a[0], a[1]);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
good_input: 20 21
```

Online demo at http://codepad.org/6G4lLXWg .

Comment: I found some test cases where this could scan to the end but ignored some characters in between. I now also read the final character '"' and control if it was read at its expected position.

Comment: Minor: Rather than `pos == strlen(s)`, suggest `s[pos] == '\0'`