# matching trailing text in sscanf?

Tags: c, scanf

This is related to [sscanf usage - how to verify a completed scan vs an aborted scan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16712860/sscanf-usage-how-to-verify-a-completed-scan-vs-an-aborted-scan) but it's an edge case not covered by that question.

```
char entry[] = "V2X_3_accepted";
int d1,d2,ret1,ret2;
ret1 = sscanf(entry,"V2X_%d_expected",&d1);
ret2 = sscanf(entry,"V2X_%d_received",&d2);
```

Expected result: `ret1==0; ret2==0; d1, d2` undefined.

Actual result: `ret1==1; ret2==1; d1=d2=3`.

Using `%n` at the end won't help, as the match strings are equal length. Is there some neat trick to match the trailing text without performing a consecutive strncmp or similar?

Comment: @user3121023: Nice! Post that as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `"%n"` works fine.  [@user3121023](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41221639/matching-trailing-text-in-sscanf#comment69642228_41221639)

Recommend using `" %n"` to allow optional trailing white-space like a `'\n'` to pass `"V2X_3_expected\n"` and to check the `%n` result to fail `"V2X_3_expected 123"`.

```
char entry[] = "V2X_3_accepted";

int d1,d2;
int n1 = 0;
int n2 = 0;

sscanf(entry,"V2X_%d_expected %n",&d1, &n1);
sscanf(entry,"V2X_%d_received %n",&d2, &n2);
if (n1 > 0 && entry[n1] == '\0') Success_expected(d1);
else if (n2 > 0 && entry[n2] == '\0') Success_received(d2);
else Fail(entry);
```

---

Initialize `n1` to a value that would never be set is scanning reached the `"%n"` specifier.  `n1 = 0;` works well in most cases like with OP's format `"V2X_%d_ ..."`.

`n1 = -1; /* and (n1 >= 0 */` also works with short formats like `" %n"`.

Answer (score -2):

The return statment of scanf tell you the number of assignation that he succeed so if you ask for one "fill"

`ret1 = sscanf(entry,"V2X_%d_expected",&d1);`

and scanf succed the return value will be 1;

So it's totally normal.

You can find more documentation about using the command line `man scanf`

Comment: This answer, unfortunately, is absolutely correct and completely useless.

Comment: My bad i've not understand the whole question